# How do Kernel use pagecache?

Tags: linux-kernel, buffer

I have a problem with pagecache that I don't understand.

As I understand, the pagecache will serve as disk cache for reading from and writing to disk. But I don't know how the kernel can map 10G memory pagecache to 200GB disk.

When reading, the kernel can only cache data that is regularly read from disk, but when writing to disk, data will be written to memory buffer and then the kernel will write to disk.

But how can memory have enough buffer when the data written to disk is very large?

Comment: Then the kernel simply don't store all data at once...?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is the list of the kernel / `sysctl` parameters that control those operations:

- [`vm.dirty_background_bytes`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_background_bytes/)
- [`vm.dirty_background_ratio`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_background_ratio/)
- [`vm.dirty_bytes`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_bytes/)
- [`vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs/)
- [`vm.dirty_ratio`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_ratio/)
- [`vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs`](https://sysctl-explorer.net/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs/)

A good and informative resource for this could be found in SUSE's article [Tuning the memory management subsystem](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-memory.html). It says it applies to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3, but it's true for most Linux distros (though the defaults might be different.

> [**Pagecache**](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-memory.html#cha-tuning-memory-usage-pagecache)
>
> A cache of file data. When a file is read from disk or network, the
> contents are stored in pagecache. No disk or network access is
> required, if the contents are up-to-date in pagecache. tmpfs and
> shared memory segments count toward pagecache.
>
> **When a file is written to, the new data is stored in pagecache before
> being written back to a disk or the network (making it a write-back
> cache). When a page has new data not written back yet, it is called
> "dirty".** Pages not classified as dirty are "clean". Clean pagecache
> pages can be reclaimed if there is a memory shortage by simply freeing
> them. Dirty pages must first be made clean before being reclaimed.
>
> [...]
>
> [**Writeback**](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-memory.html#cha-tuning-memory-usage-writeback)
>
> **As applications write to files, the pagecache becomes dirty and the
> buffercache may become dirty**. When the amount of dirty memory reaches
> a specified number of pages in bytes (`vm.dirty_background_bytes`), or
> when the amount of dirty memory reaches a specific ratio to total
> memory (`vm.dirty_background_ratio`), or when the pages have been
> dirty for longer than a specified amount of time
> (`vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`), **the kernel begins writeback of pages
> starting with files that had the pages dirtied first**. The background
> bytes and ratios are mutually exclusive and setting one will overwrite
> the other. Flusher threads perform writeback in the background and
> allow applications to continue running. If the I/O cannot keep up with
> applications dirtying pagecache, and dirty data reaches a critical
> setting (`vm.dirty_bytes` or `vm.dirty_ratio`), then applications
> begin to be throttled to prevent dirty data exceeding this threshold.

The article [Introduction to Linux Kernel Parameters](https://www.tencentcloud.com/document/product/213/39162#io-related) has a nice explanation about those:

> These parameters are mainly used to configure the policy for IO being
> written back to the disk.
>
> - `dirty_background_bytes`/`dirty_bytes` and `dirty_background_ratio`/`dirty_ratio` refer to the amount and
>   percentage of system memory that can be filled with "dirty" pages,
>   respectively. In general, the ratio will be specified.
> - `dirty_background_ratio`: refers to a percentage of dirty pages in the system memory (10% by default) at which the background kernel
>   flush processes will start writing back to the disk.
> - `dirty_ratio`: refers to the absolute maximum amount of system memory that can be filled with dirty pages before everything must get
>   committed to disk. When the system gets to this point, all new I/O
>   blocks until dirty pages have been written to disk, causing long I/O
>   pauses. The system will first get to the `vm.dirty_background_ratio`
>   condition at which the flush processes will start asynchronous
>   writeback, and applications continue writing. When the system gets to
>   the specified value of  `vm.dirty_ratio`, OS will handle dirty pages
>   synchronously, blocking applications.
> - `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs`: specifies how long dirty page can be in cache before it needs to be written. It is expressed in 100'ths of a
>   second. Data which has been dirty in-memory for longer than this
>   interval will be written out next time a flush process wakes up.
> - `vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs`: specifies how often kernel flush processes wake up. It is expressed in 100'ths of a second.

Another good elaboration about those could be found in the [Writeback parameters](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-memory.html#cha-tuning-memory-vm-writeback) section of SUSE's article [Tuning the memory management subsystem](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-memory.html) I've mentioned above.